# how to plug a 3 phases oven from the panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I’m moving to an apartment and would like to plug in an oven, the agent told me it was 1 phase condo but when I look at the panel it seems to be 3 phases.

1. Is it 1 or 3 phases?
2. If 3 phases can I use a 3 phases oven?
3. Will new wiring be needed from the panel to the plug?

Here are pictures of the panel:

[image]

[image]

Comment: We would need the schematic from the oven to know if it can be reconfigured (most heat element type can be required). The breakers are rated for multi pole use but I can not see any handle ties so all loads look to be single phase possible high voltage on the 2 with dots but I don’t see ties there either.

Comment: Most ranges and ovens have a 3-phase input, but all the elements in the oven are actually 230V elements wired phase-to-ground. That assures they work all over the 5 continents.  An oven only needs 3-phase if it has 400V elements, and that would only be in commercial gear where the customers were presumed to have 3-phase.  Which is your oven?

Answer (score 0):

For your question 1:

- That was a big label on the MCB circuit 415V Three Phase.
- The main concerns are the agent, is he okay?

For question 2:

- Yes you can if you know which cable for phase 1, 2, 3 (in this case RYB).
- Check for an electrician to make a special plug or wiring especially for 3 phase system.

For question 3: already answered in no.2 answer